# How works numpy dot for 3-D matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

how works numpy.dot for 3-D arrays.

I have:

- A with shape [15, 30, 500]
- B with shape [15]

After:

```
C = np.dot(a.T, B)
```

I receive C with shape [500, 30] but can't understand how (I want to port code to other language without numpy).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be code that others have written, and you want to understand what this case does (in particular, not in general), for the purposes of porting, I'll use a simple demonstration:

```
In [46]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4); B = np.array([10,20])                                       
In [47]: A                                                                                             
Out[47]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [48]: A.T                                                                                           
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 0, 12],
        [ 4, 16],
        [ 8, 20]],

       [[ 1, 13],
        [ 5, 17],
        [ 9, 21]],

       [[ 2, 14],
        [ 6, 18],
        [10, 22]],

       [[ 3, 15],
        [ 7, 19],
        [11, 23]]])
```

The `dot`:

```
In [50]: C = np.dot(A.T, B)                                                                            
In [51]: C                                                                                             
Out[51]: 
array([[240, 360, 480],
       [270, 390, 510],
       [300, 420, 540],
       [330, 450, 570]])
```

the same thing, but using broadcasting, elementwise multiplication and sum:

```
In [52]: (A.T * B[None,None,:]).sum(axis=2)                                                            
Out[52]: 
array([[240, 360, 480],
       [270, 390, 510],
       [300, 420, 540],
       [330, 450, 570]])
```

Or with the indexing notation of `einsum`:

```
In [53]: np.einsum('ijk,i->kj',A,B)                                                                    
Out[53]: 
array([[240, 360, 480],
       [270, 390, 510],
       [300, 420, 540],
       [330, 450, 570]])
```

An intermediate step in the elementwise multiplication:

```
In [54]: (A.T * B[None,None,:])                                                                        
Out[54]: 
array([[[  0, 240],
        [ 40, 320],
        [ 80, 400]],

       [[ 10, 260],
        [ 50, 340],
        [ 90, 420]],

       [[ 20, 280],
        [ 60, 360],
        [100, 440]],

       [[ 30, 300],
        [ 70, 380],
        [110, 460]]])
```

So it's do a dot product (scalar product) of each row of `A.T` (last dimension) with `B`.  So there's one value for the first 2 dimensions (here (4,3)).

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much.